# Setting line spread globally, but not for tables

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I use a `\linespread` of 2 globally to nicely space out a document. But when I'm doing tables, the line spacing affects the table as well, here's an example:

[image: Example of table being spread out with linespacing]

Is there a way to set the lines spacing on tables globally?

Below is an extract from my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Me}
\title{--}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    margin=20mm,
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\V}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\VH}[1]{\mathbf{\widehat{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VM}[1]{\left|\mathbf{#1}\right|}
\newcommand{\Vi}[0]{\V{i}}
\newcommand{\Vj}[0]{\V{j}}
\newcommand{\Vk}[0]{\V{k}}
\newcommand{\Vo}[0]{\V{0}}
\newcommand{\pref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\RefHB}[2]{(H.B. page #1, item #2)}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{My TMA}
\rhead{Me}
\cfoot{\thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\linespread{2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\begin{document}
\newpage\section*{Question 5}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*]
    \item The force of the damper is listed below
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering Damper\\length}&
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering Rate of change\\ of length}&
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering Damping\\constant}&
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering $\VH{s}$}&
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{3cm}|}{\centering $\V{R}$}
    \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

many thanks

Comment: 2 is rather large (much more than double spaced)  you might like the package  `setspace` that provides `\doublespace` and automatically sets it back to `\singlespace` in tables  etc

Comment: note that in the use above you should just use `\begin{center}` not `\begin{table}`  `table` is a floating environment that does not form part of the current list and may be moved to help with page breaking.